# Record and play louder volume avaudio

Tags: iphone, mp3, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder, m4a

I used the tutorial found [here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-avfoundation-framework-tutorial/) to record and playback a sound.  The recording and playback work fine, but I can barely here the sound when I play it back.  I've tried the following code:

```
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;                
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,          
                             sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
```

I add it to my "play" method, right before I play the sound.  I've also tried to add it to my `viewDidLoad`.  Both of them make it so I can't here the playback at all.  It seems to be working for others, but where should I add it?

I checked out SpeakHere, Apples example AVAudio app.  The volume is very quiet.  When I use the Voice Memos app, the recording is played back very very loud.  Has anyone been able to play a recorded message and play it back that loud?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting this property of `AVAudioPlayer` ...

```
@property float volume; /* The volume for the sound. The nominal range is from 0.0 to 1.0. */
```